# Search bar making my web page not trustable

Tags: search

I have a search bar on my website that goes to google but it is making that web page not trustable. I have ssl and all my other pages have the little lock but the page with the search has an i with a circle around it. If i take the search off the page the little lock comes back.  Can someone maybe tell me why.

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="search">
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input type="text" name="q" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search The Web"autocomplete="off" >
<button type="submit" class="searchButton">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is making your web page not trustable how exactly ?

Comment: Did you try using `https` in your action URL?